# Problem in reading from text file in my code

Tags: vb.net

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008:

```
' Create an instance of the open file dialog box.
Dim openFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

' Set filter options and filter index.
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1

openFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

' Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialogbox.
Dim UserClickedOK As Boolean = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog

' Process input if the user clicked OK.
If (UserClickedOK = True) Then
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader() ' <-----
        Dim line As String
        ' Read and display the lines from the file until the end 
        ' of the file is reached.
        Do
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(Line)
        Loop Until line Is Nothing
    End Using
End If
```

On the line marked, how can I pass the path of the selected file into the StreamReader constructor? Thanks!

Comment: Another bug - an exception will be thrown if you the user selects an empty file with no lines.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Amended my sample code as per Hans suggestion.

Just use the `FileName` property of the `OpenFileDialog` class as:

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName) 
        ' do stuff
    End Using
End If
```

Edit: Though I just saw that you've got `MultiSelect` set to `True`, so you'd have to use the `FileNames` property instead and loop through it and open the `StreamReader` for each file.

So something like:

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    For Each file As String In openFileDialog1.FileNames
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(file) 
             ' do stuff
        End Using
    Next
End If
```

Comment: ShowDialog() doesn't return a Boolean, you might want to add that.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, I always miss that just because it looks like it would make sense.